# Which feats can replace the dodge feat for meeting prerequisites?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, feat-qualifications

A lot of feats and prestige classes require the dodge feat, and I noticed that the Desert Wind Dodge feat says:

> Desert Wind Dodge can be used in place of Dodge to qualify fora feat, prestige class, or other special ability. If you already have Dodge when you select Desert Wind Dodge, you can choose to lose the Dodge feat and gain a new feat in its place. You must meet the prerequisite for the new feat.

Are there any other feats that could also be used in place of dodge, and if so, what are they? If it is possible to do so, I would greatly appreciate if they were ordered from best to worst, though I understand that might make this question opinion based.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Desert Wind Dodge, *Tome of Battle*. If you move at least 10 feet in a round, gain +1 fire damage with Desert Wind weapons and +1 dodge bonus to AC.
- Expeditious Dodge, *Races of the Wild*. Same dodge bonus as Dodge, but against all foes—but only if you move at least 40 feet in a round.
- Midnight Dodge, *Magic of Incarnum*. As Dodge, except that the dodge bonus to AC is equal to the amount of essentia invested in the feat, and you gain 1 bonus essentia. Easily the best option—just for the extra essentia, you should never actually invest any essentia in it.

<s>Off the top of my head.</s> Double checked, had them all and most of the details, though I forgot Desert Wind Dodge was restricted to Desert Wind weapons and that Midnight Dodge still only applied to one foe.

Ultimately, all of these are pretty bad feats. Expeditious Dodge might be the choice for a charger who doesn’t have any meldshaping, but otherwise you should probably take Midnight Dodge and maybe someday you’ll do something with incarnum. Desert Wind Dodge only makes sense for a scout/swordsage or something, which is a kind of neat idea but not actually a *good* one.

Comment: Yeah, I knew they were bad, but if you're trying to get into Master of Nine, what can you do? Oh, well.

Comment: @TheDragonOfFlame Dip cleric for Darkness and Time domains, and use unarmed swordsage; then you only have to pick up Adaptive Style, and Dodge or one of these replacements. It helps, anyway. For master of nine, though, I’d still favor Midnight Dodge.

Comment: Even though I would have no use for the essentia?

Comment: @TheDragonOfFlame If you have planned out an entire 20-level build (or to whatever level you _know_ the campaign will end at), and you have no space for any incarnum, then OK, maybe Desert Wind Dodge is the choice (assuming a master of nine can easily pick up at least one Desert Wind maneuver, and doesn’t have fast movement), but short of that, I think I’d prefer to leave myself the option of maybe someday doing something with incarnum than I would the situational +1 AC.

Comment: @TheDragonOfFlame The other thing that can complicate things here is that a master of nine often delays swordsage until 5th, in order to get bonus feats or other features to make up for all the feats burned qualifying for master of nine, and to start with 2nd-level maneuvers. But if you do that, you only get one feat, at 6th, between your first level of swordsage and when you want to start master of nine—and both Adaptive Style and Desert Wind Dodge require things that you only get once you have the swordsage level, so you can’t take them before that. That nixes Desert Wind Dodge.

Comment: I checked my notes for ways to gain the _Dodge_ feat for free. Outside of Unearthed Arcana, the Hadozee Race may or may not get it: the description in Stormwrack (p. 42) does not give it, however the later description of Hadozee as Character (p. 152) does... Not sure if there's been an errata.